# Recorded Audio using Native Audio Recorder Issue

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am recording audio using Audio recorder (native app) of android.Using following code :

```
final Intent audioIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();
            File AudioFolder = new File(path + "/MyFolder/",
                    "RecordedAudio");
            File audioFile = new File(AudioFolder, "myaudio.mp4");
            Uri audioFileUri = Uri.fromFile(audioFile);
            audioIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, audioFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(audioIntent, 0);
```

Audio recording is working fine with me. After successful recording It has been stored default  in sdcard. I am not able to store it with my particular folder "MyFolder" that is located in sdcard so It might be store in /sdcard/Myfolder/RecordedAudio/myaudio.mp4.

What is going wrong with my above code.?

Please help me with your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @KumarBibek : I'm not getting any error. I'm not able to store audio file in particular folder as I have suggested. Default It has been stored in SDCARD only. I want to store it with particular folder in sdcard for that I have also right code as per above. So now what is wrong with that code?

Comment: Can you check logcat if it shows any error..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar : No error bro. It has been stored in sdcard successfully. I'm not able to store it with my particular folder only.

Comment: when you launch this code with your folder and with SDCARD only do you see any difference in logcat logs... can you share the logs for these two use case....

Comment: Check for "FileNotFoundException". Are you sure you have created those directories prior to writing to that file?

Comment: @KumarBibek : No exception found. Yes I have that directory to store that file . I m sure..

Comment: 'String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Your_Dir_name/";
File file = new File(folderPath);
if (!file.exists()) {
  file.mkdirs();
 }'